# Highlight button if field is not null C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I was hoping someone could share some code relative to "flagging" rows in a gridview.  The first column of my gv is a column of buttons that bring up a new window based on the item listed in that row.

I would like to highlight the button (or the row in some other way) if one of two conditions (or both) is true.

The window pop-up that opens with the button click shows a small gv if data exists as well as a Comments formview.  So I would highlight if that gv appears (meaning the data exists--query for this is already written) or if the Comments field is not null.

Little tricky since the two conditions work off different SPs and different source tables, but getting a highlight for at least one would still be a huge step.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the `RowDataBound` event of the Gridview. If a certain condition is met, then you can change the color of that row to distinguish it from other rows. For example:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

    if(dr["ColumnName"] && dr["ColumnName1"])
    {
      e.Row.Style.Add("Color", "Red");         
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does Row.Style.Add color the whole row or just outline? (I'd prefer to just outline but don't want to be picky).  More importantly, there is already a few RowDataBound if events for this GV...they can co-exist right?